# What should we do If we have Or condition in INNER JOIN with EF Linq?

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I the code below I have a TSql query which has Or condition in its join. If I want to convert it to Linq in C# how can I rewrite it.

```sql
    SELECT P.Id AS ProductId
      FROM generalinv.InventoryTypeProductTypeMapping AS ITM
INNER JOIN master.Product AS P 
        ON (P.ProductCategoryId = ISNULL(ITM.ProductCategoryId, 0))
        OR (P.ProductTypeId = ISNULL(ITM.ProductTypeId, 0))
```

Comment: No. It is inner join with condition OR instead of AND

Comment: An equivalent query would take the union of the same query but with separate join conditions.

Comment: @JeffMercado Would you please leave your answer

Comment: Join can be expressed by [Collection selector references outer in a where clause](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/complex-query-operators#collection-selector-references-outer-in-a-where-clause) also.

Comment: Split into two queries and union both of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you have a table of `generalinv.InventoryTypeProductTypeMappings`, each row is called one ITM. And you have a table of `master.Products`, where every row is called a P.

### Generic solution

You want to select several properties from the combination (ITM, P), for those ITMs and Ps where predicate (1) is valid: `P.ProductCategoryId = ISNULL(ITM.ProductCategoryId, 0)`, or where predicate (2) is valid: `(P.ProductTypeId = ISNULL(ITM.ProductTypeId, 0))`

So you want to select the (ITM, P) combination if predicate (1) matches, or if predicate (2) matches. It might be that both predicates match, in that case you want just one (ITM, P) combination.

How about you join on predicate (1), and join on predicate (2), do a UNION, and remove duplicates. Something like this:

I do this in smaller steps, so you understand what happens

First I'll do a join on predicate (1):

```
var result1 = generalinv.InventoryTypeProductTypeMapping
    .Join(master.Product,

    p => p.ProductCategoryId,          // from each P take the ProductCategoryId
    itm => itm.ProductCategoryId ?? 0, // from each itm take the ProductCategoryId
                                       // or zero if the ProductCategoryId equals null

    // parameter resultSelector: for simplicity, keep the combination (ITM, P)
    (p, itm) => new
    {
        ITM = itm,
        P = p,
    });
```

After that I do a join on predicate 2:

```
var result2 = generalinv.InventoryTypeProductTypeMapping
    .Join(master.Product,

    p => p.ProductCategoryId,          // from each P take the ProductTypeId
    itm => itm.ProductCategoryId ?? 0, // from each itm take the ProductTypeId
                                       // or zero if the ProductTypeId equals null
    // parameter resultSelector: same as in result1.
    (p, itm) => new
    {
        ITM = itm,
        P = p,
    });
```

Unite result1 and result2, remove duplicates and select the properties that you want to keep.

```
var result = result1.Union(result2)
                    .Distinct()
                    .Select(combinationItmP => new
                    {
                        // Select the properties from (ITM, P) combination that you want to use.
                        ...
                    });
```

### Keeping only P.Id can be done a bit simpler

It seems that you only want to keep P.Id. In that case we can make it easier by changing parameter resultSelector:

```
// parameter resultSelector: keep only P.Id:
(p, itm) => p.Id);
```

Unite result1 and result2, and remove duplicates:

```
var result = result1.Union(result2).Distinct();
```

Answer (score 1):

i think you looking for something like this:

this is Linq to SQL:

```
var result = from ITM in InventoryTypeProductTypeMappings
                from P in Products
                where (P.ProductCategoryId == (ITM.ProductCategoryId == null ? 0 : ITM.ProductCategoryId)
                    || P.ProductTypeId == (ITM.ProductTypeId == null ? 0 : ITM.ProductTypeId))
                select P.ID
                ;
result.Dump();
```

or different syntax

```
var res2 = from t1 in InventoryTypeProductTypeMappings
    from t2 in Products.Where(x => x.ProductCategoryId == (t1.ProductCategoryId == null ? 0 : t1.ProductCategoryId)
                            || x.ProductTypeId == (t1.ProductTypeId == null ? 0 : t1.ProductTypeId))
                            .DefaultIfEmpty()
    select t2.ID;
```